# SQL Query Help - Duplicate Removal

Tags: asp.net, sql, duplicates

wasn't sure whether to put this in Software or here, so I figured I'd start here  I know this will be a straightforward answer from you SQL geniuses...

I have a table, it contains contacts that I import on a daily basis. I will have an ASP.NET front end for user interaction. From this table, my intention is to send them all mailers - but only one to each address. So my end result is a user enters a date (which corresponds to teh date imported) and they are given a resultant grid that has all the unique addresses associated to that date. I only want to send a mailer to that address once - many times my original imported list will contain multiple businesses at the same address.

Table: ContactTable
Fielsd:
ID, CompanyName, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone

I can use the SELECT DISTINCT clause, but I need all the data associated to it (company name, etc.)

I have over 262000 Records in this table.

If I select a sample date of 1/10/2011, I get 2401 records. SELECT DISTINCT Address from the same date gives me 2092 records. This is workable, I would send those 2092 people a mailer.

Secondly, I'd have to be able to historically check if a mailer was already sent to that address as well. I would not want to send another mailer to the same business tomorrow either.

What's my best way?

Comment: Are your addresses cleansed/standardized so they're guaranteed identical? For instance, "123 Main St." vs. "123 Main Street", "St. Louis MO" vs. "Saint Louis MO", etc.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not cleaned 100%.  We get these daily lists from a company, and truth be told - it is not always clean data.  We are aware there will be some error occurence due to this, although is there some tuning I can do to the table prior to clean it up a bit further?

Comment: Do you need the ID column in your results?  It really looks like a simple DISTINCT or GROUP BY would work if you removed the ID column (e.g. SELECT CompanyName, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone FROM ContactTable GROUP BY CompanyName, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone).

Comment: Zack - I would like to keep the ID for updating an secondary table.  Once the mailers have been sent, I would like to update a Mailed table with the IDs so that they are not mailed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would select, then remove, the duplicates like this:

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.PurgedID, a.CAMPAIGNTYPE, a.COMPANY, a.DBANAME, a.COADDRESS, a.COCITY, a.COSTATE, a.COZIP, a.FIRSTNAME1, a.DIALERPHONENUM, a.Purged FROM PurgeReportDetail a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM PurgeReportDetail b WHERE
    b.COADDRESS = a.COADDRESS
    AND b.COCITY = a.COCITY
    AND b.COSTATE = a.COSTATE
    AND b.COZIP = a.COZIP
    AND b.id <> a.id
    ) -- This clause will only include rows with duplicate columns noted
AND a.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 c.ID from PurgeReportDetail c 
    WHERE c.COADDRESS = a.COADDRESS
    AND c.COCITY = a.COCITY
    AND c.COSTATE = a.COSTATE
    AND c.COZIP = a.COZIP
    ORDER BY c.ID -- If you want the *newest* entry to be saved, add "DESC" here
    ) -- This clause gets the top 1 ID value for each matching set
```

or something like this.
This will keep the first ID of the redundant address, just replace the `SELECT` with `DELETE` when ready.

EDIT: Of course this will only work on *exact* matches.

EDIT2: If you wanted to only check where you hadn't sent mailers, you should join both to a table of sent mailers from a specified date range

Comment: Matthew, I attempted to utilize your solution but it resulted in errors.  I'm no SQL Guru - but the Query continually changed on me.  See example:

Comment: SELECT ID, PurgedID, CAMPAIGNTYPE, COMPANY, DBANAME, COADDRESS, COCITY, COSTATE, COZIP, FIRSTNAME1, DIALERPHONENUM, Purged
FROM dbo.PurgeReportDetail AS A WHERE (ID IN (SELECT TOP (1) C.ID FROM dbo.PurgeReportDetail AS B WHERE (C.COADDRESS = A.COADDRESS) AND (C.COCITY = A.COCITY) AND (C.COSTATE = A.COSTATE) AND (C.COZIP = A.COZIP) ORDER BY C.ID)) AND EXISTS (SELECT ID, PurgedID, CAMPAIGNTYPE, COMPANY, DBANAME, COADDRESS, COCITY, COSTATE, COZIP, FIRSTNAME1, DIALERPHONENUM, Purged FROM dbo.PurgeReportDetail AS

Comment: c
 WHERE (COADDRESS = A.COADDRESS) AND (COCITY = A.COCITY) AND (COSTATE = A.COSTATE) AND (COZIP = A.COZIP) AND (ID <> ID))

Comment: The query you placed here doesn't match the table and column names from your OP. The idea is that you are looking for matches in the same table *without* matching ID values.

Comment: Make sure you assign each column with the matching table alias you want to use. You did not do this in your query you copied here.

Comment: That is my fault - I was using the example in the OP as strictly that - an example. The above query is copied directly from SSMS.

Comment: Yes, and the query you pasted is invalid because you do not qualify the ID values. You must use the prefix (such as a.ID, b.ID, c.ID etc) In your pasted code, you don't have it...

Comment: Try it now, I have put in your real column names.... It will return all duplicated rows (leaving the earliest existing row, having the lowest ID value)

Comment: I received this error when attempting your query. The multi-part identifier "c.ID" could not be bound.

Appreciate this help so far Matthew!

Comment: Scratch that.  I tried copying it to notepad and formatting it simliar to the way you have it and it ran, I'm waiting for results :)  Over 250K records to sort!

Comment: Matthew - It looks like I was able to get some cleaned results, which is a giant step in the right direction.  I think I'm a bit confused as to how this works mechanically, I understand what and how you're doing the statement, which is surprising :).  If I wanted to additionally filter by date, for example just give me the same results shown but only for this date (Assuming Date field exists in PurgeDetailReport) where would I put that in the statement?  Everywhere I put a clause, it resulted in an error.  Thanks a lot, btw!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, filter by date.... what do you want to do with the date? Only include as duplicates items which are on the same date?

Comment: Let me explain exactly what the function currently does.  We get daily lists of businesses, and we import them to the table PurgeDetailReport.  Those are time stamped in a separate table as to when they were imported. Every day, I am going to have to extract the business for a mailer on a daily basis.  So I believe how I envision it to function is a user would input a date on a page, and it would spit out the businesses that are unique for that date.  Further, I think I'd like it to exclude business addresses that have been sent before.  Maybe a second table like suggested before,

Comment: that has the ID #s in a separate table and marked as mailed.  Is that a better clarification? I have already built the import capability, as well as other functions on the front end of putting the businesses names into the database, as well as the ASP.NET front end page, but I'm unsure of how to give unique results on a daily basis, which is where this question came from.

Comment: For a date search, you need only add `AND a.DATE =  your-date-here` to the end. You can use the same logic to ignore rows having some `a.AlreadySent = 1`

Comment: I never actually completed this as the results I was receiving were incorrect but I understand the mechanics behind this and will attempt a different solution based on what was learned.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with creating a table to lookup sent mailers.

```
ID | DateSent
-------------
```

Every time  you send a mailer you are going to want to insert the ID, and the DateTime into it, this way when you go to pull the mailers you can look against this table to see if the mailer has been sent within whatever your specified time frame of mailing is. You can extend this if you have multiple types of mailers to include the mailer type.

**Plain Old SQL**

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CompanyName, b.Address, b.City, b.State, b.Zip, a.Phone
FROM a.ContactTable
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Address, City, State, Zip
            FROM ContactTable) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

This sub-query is like creating a temp table SELECTing only the DISTINCT addresses, then joining it to the rest of the info.

To add the lookup against your new table add the following

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CompanyName, b.Address, b.City, b.State, b.Zip, a.Phone
FROM a.ContactTable
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Address, City, State, Zip
            FROM ContactTable) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
RIGHT JOIN SentMailer c
ON a.ID = c.ID
```

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, c.DateSent, GETDATE()) > 12 --gives you everything that hasn't been sent a mailer within the last year
```

**Edit**

Without the data being standardized it's hard to get quality results. I've found in the past the more *creative* I have to get with my queries is a flag to bad table structure or data collection. I think you should still create a lookup table for ID/DateSent to manage the time frames for sending.

**Edit**

> Yes, I'm basically looking for the unique address, city, state, zip. I would only require one instance for each address so we would be able to send a mailer to that address. At this point, Company name would not be required.

If this is the case you can simply do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Address, City, State, Zip, Phone
FROM ContactTable
```

Keep in mind this won't scrub entries like `Main Street` vs `Main St.`

Comment: I attempted 

SELECT a.ID, a.CompanyName, b.Address, b.City, b.State, b.Zip, a.Phone FROM a.ContactTable RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Address, City, State, Zip FROM ContactTable) b ON a.ID = b.ID 

But was given an error of ID does not exist.  Assumedly because ID does not exist in the sub-query.

Comment: You're right... I missed that. @Joe Stefanelli is correct however...the quality of your output is only as good as the quality of your input. If the data is not valid you will get duplicates regardless. I will update my answer.

Comment: If I place ID into the sub-query - does that negate the Distinct statement?  Wouldn't the Distinct statement now be a moot point since they all have unique IDs?

Comment: Also, when I attempt with ID in the statement, the initial ID instance, continually attempts to default to b.ID.

Comment: Last thing, lol. I fixed the statement. Here is what it looks like, but in running it I get all the records from the table.

SELECT     dbo.PurgeReportDetail.ID, dbo.PurgeReportDetail.COMPANY, dbo.PurgeReportDetail.COADDRESS, dbo.PurgeReportDetail.COCITY, dbo.PurgeReportDetail.COSTATE, 
                      dbo.PurgeReportDetail.COZIP, dbo.PurgeReportDetail.DIALERPHONENUM
FROM         dbo.PurgeReportDetail RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT COADDRESS, COCITY, COSTATE, COZIP, ID
 FROM dbo.PurgeReportDetail AS PurgeReportDetail_1) AS B ON dbo.PurgeReportDetail.ID = B.ID

Comment: Yes, adding the ID negates the functionality. Are there multiple Companies at the same address? If not you may be able to ignore ID altogether. If you just need the company name and address you should be able to do a distinct on that.

Comment: Yes, I'm basically looking for the unique address, city, state, zip. I would only require one instance for each address so we would be able to send a mailer to that address.  At this point, Company name would not be required.

Comment: Jon - Thanks for your help so far.  If I run the statement with your second example, I will not have the ID to write back to the Mailed table. Second, I'm missing the business name to put onto the mailer piece.

Answer (score 1):

RogueSpear, I work in the address verification (and thus de-duplication) field for [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com), where we deal with this scenario a lot and tackle the challenge.

If you're getting daily lists from a company and have hundreds of thousands of records, then removing duplicate addresses using stored procedures or mere queries won't be enough to match the varying possibilities of each address. There *are* services which do this, and I'd point you to CASS-Certified vendors which provide that.

You can flag duplicates in a table using something like [CASS-Certified Scrubbing](https://www.smartystreets.com/Products/CASS-Certified-Scrubbing/), or you can prevent duplicates at point-of-entry with an API like [LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/). Anyway, I'd be happy to personally help you with any other address questions.